# Non-Flash Screen Recorder

Tags: macos, screen-capture, adobe-flash, video-capture

Currently, I use Jing on my Mac OSX with my team to make a short 5 minute screen recording (with optional voice record). Unfortunately, it doesn't save it in a format that can be viewed on iPads or iPhones because it is recorded in Flash. Is there a free screen recorder out there which does the same thing but stores it in webm format?

The problem with Googling for this is that I'm finding that there's a lot of malware for Mac popping up now. Where, if you install the application, it puts adware on your Mac as well.

Comment: Free screen recorder - Quicktime Player. Built-in, no ads.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tetsujin mentioned in the comment use builtin QuickTime Player. Simply choose **File** -> **New Screen Recording...** or press <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>. You can record the whole screen or selected area.

Comment: This creates a massive file and then I have to use Handbrake to convert the file, which is cumbersome to use, tedious, and slow. Got anything that uses lossy video/sound compression that reduces the file format, and makes a format that can be viewed on Windows, Mac, iOS, and Android? Would be nice if in a single tool. I'd even pay for it -- it's so important to me and my team. I just can't get something with malware/adware in it.